# SQL Query - COUNT for combination of two or more column from single table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with below column & row values and want a resultset as given below. I tried many queries but could not getthe resultset which I want.
Is there any simplest way to achieve this.

```
Column1 Column2  Column3 Column4 Column5
AAA     000000      BG1   12345   North
AAA     111111      BG2   23456   South
BBB     000000      BG3   12346   EAST
AAA     000000      BG2   12345   West

Select Column1,Count( Distinct Column1,Column2),Count(Distinct Column1,Column3),Count(Column1,Column4,Column5) From #Temp
```

**Expected Resultset:**

```
Name C2Count C3Count C4Count
AAA    2      2        3     
BBB    1      1        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anyway to avoid doing two separate aggregations.  One can handle the single distinct counts while the other can handle the two column count:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        Column1 AS Name,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Column2) AS C2Count,
        COUNT(DISTINCT Column3) AS C3Count
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Column1
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS C45Count
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT Column1 AS Name, Column4, Column5 FROM yourTable
    ) t
    GROUP BY Name
)

SELECT
    t1.Name,
    t1.C2Count,
    t1.C3Count,
    t2.C45Count
FROM cte1 t1
INNER JOIN cte2 t2
    ON t1.Name = t2.Name;
```

### Demo

Comment: I want count from combination of two or three columns for c4 count. I could not get this. Please let me know if there is any simplest way.

Comment: @Ask_SO I fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for this ? :

```
DECLARE 
    @tb TABLE
    (
        Column1 VARCHAR(50)
    ,   Column2 VARCHAR(50)
    ,   Column3 VARCHAR(50)
    ,   Column4 INT
    ,   Column5 VARCHAR(50)
    )
INSERT INTO @tb VALUES 
('AAA','000000','BG1',12345,'North'),
('AAA','111111','BG2',23456,'South'),
('BBB','000000','BG3',12346,'EAST'),
('AAA','000000','BG2',12345,'West')

SELECT
    Column1 [Name]
,   COUNT(DISTINCT Column2) C2Count 
,   COUNT(DISTINCT Column3) C3Count 
,   SUM(C45Count) C4Count
FROM (
    SELECT *, COUNT(Column1) OVER(PARTITION BY Column1, Column4, Column5) C45Count
    FROM @tb 
) D
GROUP BY 
    Column1
```

Comment: This coincidentally happens to generate the correct output, but the OP seems to want the distinct count of columns 4 and 5.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If we group by Column1, and count, isn't going to give us the same count as counting column1 ? not sure, maybe I'm missing something out. I've also updated the query to fit OP request.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused on how you are wanting the C4count calculated. Using this data(thanks @iSR5):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
    (
        Column1 VARCHAR(50)
    ,   Column2 VARCHAR(50)
    ,   Column3 VARCHAR(50)
    ,   Column4 INT
    ,   Column5 VARCHAR(50)
    )
INSERT INTO #Table VALUES 
('AAA','000000','BG1',12345,'North'),
('AAA','111111','BG2',23456,'South'),
('BBB','000000','BG3',12346,'EAST'),
('AAA','000000','BG2',12345,'West')
```

You can use a pretty basic Statement to achieve the desired results:

```
SELECT   Column1 AS [Name]
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.Column2) AS C2Count
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT t.Column3) AS C3Count
        ,COUNT(t.Column4) AS C4Count
FROM #Table t
GROUP BY t.Column1
```

Results:

```
Name C2Count C3Count C4Count
AAA    2      2        3     
BBB    1      1        1
```

This will count how many distinct matches are in each column for AAA and BBB for column2 and column 3, and count overall matches for column4. Your desired results don't show anything for column5.

If there is some other sort of calculation you are wanting, could you please **clearly** describe what you are looking for so I can adjust my code to show what it is you are looking for.